# "this" captured by lambda is incorrect. GCC compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, arm, compiler-bug

For the last few days, I have been debugging a weird issue involving lambdas in C++. I have reduced the problem down to the following symptoms:

- **The `this` pointer gets corrupted inside a lambda** (note: `this` is always captured by copy, so the lambda should get its own `this` pointer, which points to the `App` object)
- **It only occurs if a `std::cout` print statement is present**, and called before the lambda is created. The print statement can be seemingly completely unrelated (e.g. print "Hello!"). `printf()` also exhibits the same behaviour.
- **It only occurs** when cross-compiling.
- It compiles and runs fine with the standard compiler for `x86` architecture (see [example](http://cpp.sh/9ru5k)).
- If I create the lambda on the heap (and save a pointer to it inside the `App` object), the bug does not occur.
- **The bug does not occur if optimizations are turned off** (i.e. if I set the `-O0` flag). It occurs when optimization is set to `-O2`.

The following is the simplest, compilable code example I could come up with that causes the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class App {

public:

    std::function<void*()> test_;

    void Run() {

        // Enable this line, ERROR is printed
        // Disable this line, app runs o.k.
        std::cout << "This print statement causes the bug below!" << std::endl;

        test_ = [this] () {
            return this;
        };

        void* returnedThis = test_();
        if(returnedThis != this) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: 'this' returned from lambda (" << returnedThis 
                      << ") is NOT the same as 'this' (" << this << ") !?!?!?!?!"
                      << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Program run successfully." << std::endl;
        }

    }
};

int main(void) {
    App app;
    app.Run();
}
```

When running on the target device, I get the following output:

```
This print statement causes the bug below!
ERROR: 'this' returned from lambda (0xbec92dd4) is NOT the same as 'this' 
(0xbec92c68) !?!?!?!?!
```

If I try and dereference the corrupted `this`, I usually get a segmentation fault, which is how I discovered the bug in the first place.

## Compiler Settings

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -std=c++14 \
-mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 \
--sysroot=/home/ghunter/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi \
-O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types
```

## Linker Settings

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld \
--sysroot=/home/ghunter/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi \
-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed
```

## Compiler Version

```
~$ arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ (GCC) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Could this be a compiler bug?

Comment: *Only occurs if a std::cout print statement is present*  **Massive UB flag**  (with ~100% success rate of this being the case in the past for me) to me, try running your program under valgrind

Comment: I narrowed the source code in order to avoid a horizontal scroll bar.  I would suggest doing the same for the compiler and linker settings ... but I feel a lot less confident I can edit those without introducing errors.

Comment: First rule of thumb - it's never a compiler bug, it's always UB in your code.  (I have found a compiler bug once though.)  Can you move declaration of the variable `test_` into the body of `Run`?  If so, can you move the body of `Run` into `main()`?

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for the suggestion, I have done so, using the `\\` character.

Comment: Any reason to use `void*` instead of `App*` ?

Comment: Does using `void* p = this; test_ = [p] () { return p; };` also produce the error ?

Comment: @MartinBonner, if I declare the lambda inside the body of `Run`, the bug does not occur, e.g. `auto test = [this] () { return this; };`. It seems as though the lambda needs to be copied to the `App` object and then called for bug to occur.

Comment: @Jarod42 or simply `auto`.

Comment: @gbmhunter: lambda is different that `std::function`.

Comment: If you change `void* returnedThis = test_();` to `void* returnedThis = static_cast<void*>(this);` do you get the same thing?

Comment: Works fine with GCC.7.1 on Debian/Sid/x86-64

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, the bug still occurs with the code `void* p = this; test_ = [p] () { return p; };`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Here I really talk about variable type. `auto` is just a convenient way to hide(/don't bother of) type. I really talk about conversion/promotion between type.

Comment: @NathanOliver, no, the bug does not occur if I change `void* returnedThis = test_();` to `void* returnedThis = static_cast<void*>(this);`. It seems as though the lambda needs to be created and then used for this to occur.

Comment: If instead of the `std::function` you use `auto test_ = [this] () {
            return this;
        };` (so that `test_` is of the type of the lambda rather than converted to `std::function`) does the bug still reproduce?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, if I use `auto test_ = [this] () { return this; };` (declare and use the lambda inside `Run()`, and don't copy to `std::function` member variable of `App`), then no, the bug does not occur.

Comment: @Curious: If I compile for Ubuntu and run under valgrind, I get the message `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`. I can look into compiling and installing valgrind on the target architecture to test the cross-compiled code, but this will be a non-trivial task (can't respond right away with an answer).

Comment: @gbmhunter don't know much about cross compilers and haven't used many in the past.  I don't think I will be of further help here, good luck!

Comment: @gbmhunter Starting to smell like a bug to me. At least enough that think it's reasonable to open a GCC bug report. You have gathered quite a bit of relevant examples of working/not-working variants that it should be possible to write a high quality bug report and either get confirmation that it's a bug or a fair chance of an explanation of why it is not (if that's the case). If you *do* open a bug, please add a link to it in the question for us to follow along with.

Comment: @JesperJuhl o.k. will do. I guess I file the bug at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/, even though this is using the compiler with file name `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++` (I believe that the "Yocto" build system I am using is just building g++ v6.2 with specific compiler flags and then renaming the output).

Comment: Does the bug still occur if you use `App*` instead of `void*` in both places?

Comment: It might be illuminating to look at the generated assembly for this program

Comment: @M.M, yes the bug still occurs if I replace `void*` with `App*`. I have generated assembly output for the above code (warning, it is a large file) at https://gist.github.com/gbmhunter/63c8babd7c8f0e794bb80d53e71331cd

Comment: can you try volatile std::function<void*()> test_; I had cases were some compiler would wrongly optimize some variable. Adding volatile would force them not optimizing (removing) some variables.

Comment: You say the error occurs with `printf`, does it occur with `puts`?

Comment: I have compiled this with ARM aarch64 GCC 6.3 under Debian and it executes successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a compiler bug in gcc 6.2, see:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77686

Workarounds:

- Use `-fno-schedule-insns2` flag (as pointed out by gbmhunter, see comment below).
- Do not use `-O2` optimizations or higher.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to be the bug. As mentioned in the linked mailing list, adding the flag `-fno-schedule-insns2` (which disables instruction scheduling) also fixes the issue. This allows you to keep your optimization level at `-O2` or `-O3` (note however `-fno-schedule-insns2` may still affect the speed of your code).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the following compiler bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77933  (which only effects code generated with O1 optimizations or higher).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will look into this to confirm in the next 3 days or so, and accept this answer if so :-)

Comment: I actually ran out of time to fully verify (i.e. closely inspect the assembly code and compare against the recorded bug). But since it matches this bug description exactly (e.g. only occurs with optimization O1 or higher, on the older versions of GCC, and corrupts the stack) I am accepting this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I really don't think it is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77933 as.... 1. I have applied the patch and it still fails. 2. That bug is in __builtin_return_address()... and I can't see that being anywhere near this problem.

Comment: @JohnCarter yes could catch. See Philipp Huppertz's answer, I believe he has found the correct bug.